# How to insert new line (after cursor point) with indentation?

Tags: emacs

I works in programming mode such as `javascript-mode` and usually need to push some lines down for formatting purpose.

I find `C-o` convenient to insert a newline after cursor point. However the line pushed down loses its indentation.

I find `RET` convenient to insert newline. And the line pushed down is nicely indented. However, the inserted new-line comes after the current cursor point. (EDIT: ) I find it is convenient to keep the cursor position by inserting the newline after it, because sometimes I still need to modify the current line.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
(defun open-line-and-indent ()
  "Like `newline-and-indent', but do not move the point."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (newline-and-indent)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") #'open-line-and-indent)
;; (define-key javascript-mode-map (kbd "C-o") #'open-line-and-indent)
```